# Term for the converse of "instrumental"

Tags: grammar, terminology

We can make a noun for the instrument of an action, by taking the verb for the action and adding an **instrumental** marker.<sup>[1]</sup>

For instance, in English, we can add "-er",<sup>[2]</sup> like so:

> I **cut** the box with a box-**cutter**.

Conversely, we can make a verb for an action, by taking the noun for the instrument and adding... **what could you call it?**

In English, we don't necessarily have an affix, since we can just verbalise the noun, like so:

> I will **knife** you with my **knife**.

...but we might use "-ise" this way, at least jocularly:

> I will **hammerise** him if he comes at me with that knife.

So is there a term for such a marker, indicating the **use** of an instrument? "Usive"? "Usual"?

---

[1] I was going to call this "instrumentive", on the pattern of "agentive" and "patientive", but the word doesn't appear in any dictionary I checked. It is used in some books on linguistics, though, per Google Books.

[2] This is also the agentive suffix in English, but I'm imagining a scenario where the agent and the instrument are clearly distinguished.

Comment: I have never come across a specific term for this -- generally it is a verb derived from a noun, in the sense that it is the action associated with that noun. So you could call it _verbalisation_, or _verbification_, as _verbalisation_ also means to put something into words. I would also guess that this is fairly specific to English, as it's got a somewhat fluid word class system.

Comment: @OliverMason: Yeah, I had "verbalise" already, but was hoping for something more specific. And as it happens, I had this question while pondering a system inspired by Latin: verb → -atus (past participle used as verbal noun) → -ator (agentive noun) → -atory (noun for place or practice of the agent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're conflating a/o confusing a couple different things here.

First, "cutter" is not "instrumental". (At least in English!) In English grammar, **-er** is (among zillions of other uses) the morpheme that indicates "agent noun"; so, *cutter* means "thing that cuts". It is the actual agent by which cutting happens.

The **[Instrumental Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case)** is a grammatical function that indicates the means by which the agent or subject of the verb does the action:

- I-subj cut-verb the.box-obj (with.a.box.cutter)-instr.

If English had case endings like Latin, you could see the difference easily:

- Puer-NOM cistam-ACC cultello-ABL secavit-VERB

Latin uses the ablative case to denote the instrumental case, due to ancient case syncretism of the old ablative, locative and instrumental cases.

**[-ise / -ize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ize)**, in English, is a grammatical morpheme that indicates the word is a denominal verb. This means that the verb in question is made from a noun. We already know that English weirds. It verbs nouns at the drop of a hat.

- I will **hammer** him if he attacks me with the knife.

Your example, "I will hammerise him if he attacks me with a knife", doesn't actually make sense in context. This is because **-ise** doesn't mean "use something as an instrument", it means "turn something into something else".

- Immigrants ought to be *Americanised* through educational programmes.
- The machine *pulverises* large pieces of stone into gravel.

---

I think your best bet, as far as "converse" of or "opposite" of the instrumental case, would be the

**noninstrumental case**, which I just made up.  It does what the instrumental case does, only in the other direction. Essentially, the speaker denies the instrumentality of the named article.

- Puer-NOM cistam-ACC cultellei-NONINST secavit-VERB

I considered "deinstrumental", but that's already a thing (a noun or verb made upon an instrumental form).

Comment: "English weirds"—love it. Conflating, yes, but I thought I said as much in my post. English doesn't have distinct grammatical forms for what I was trying to describe, and I don't actually know Latin—just enough to explore Latinate English forms and/or be dangerous and/or get conlang ideas.

Comment: Revisiting (much later!) and accepting. I do disagree with you that "-ise" can't be instrumental. I don't recall now what specific example I was thinking of at the time, though I'm sure I had one! But I do have an example now where it's clearly not "turn into the thing", and is *arguably* instrumental: "brutalise". If I brutalise someone, I *use* brutality on them.